# Formatting alignment of uipickerview

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have searched and cannot find anything that can help me format the alignment of each row in my pickerview.

Currently it looks like this:

[image: PoundsPence_PickerView]

What I would like to do is right justify the left £ row and left justify the right pence row so that there is no gap and the current value would be £25.31 instead or the large gap that exists now.

I found some code that formats backgrounds and font size but not alignment.

Any help or links would be appreciated.

This is my full ViewController code...

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class LocationViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var DisplayStartMileage: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelFuelAmount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var spinFuelAmount: UIPickerView!

    var mileageToPass: String!

    var fuelAmount: Double = 0.00

    var pickerData = [[String]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var poundValues = [String]()
        var penceValues = [String]()
        for var indexP:Int = 0; indexP < 100; indexP += 1 {
            poundValues.append("£ \(indexP)")
            penceValues.append(NSString(format: ".%02d", indexP) as String)
        }

        self.pickerData = [poundValues, penceValues]

        spinFuelAmount.delegate = self
        spinFuelAmount.dataSource = self

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func FuelSegmentChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex
        {
        case 0:
            labelFuelAmount.hidden = false
            spinFuelAmount.hidden = false

        case 1:
            labelFuelAmount.hidden = true
            spinFuelAmount.hidden = true

        default:
            break; 
        }

    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(spinFuelAmount: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView(spinFuelAmount: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData[component].count
    }

    func pickerView(spinFuelAmount: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return pickerData[component][row]
    }

    func pickerView(spinFuelAmount: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        var firstComponent = pickerData[0][spinFuelAmount.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
        firstComponent = firstComponent.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( "£ ", withString: "" )

        var secondComponent = pickerData[1][spinFuelAmount.selectedRowInComponent(1)]
        secondComponent = secondComponent.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( ".", withString: "" )

        if let firstValue = firstComponent.toInt(), let secondValue = secondComponent.toInt() {
            let fuelAmount = firstValue + secondValue / 100
        }

    }

    func pickerView(spinFuelAmount: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {

        let titleData = pickerData[row]
        var myString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string:titleData)
        let myString1Font1 = UIFont(name:"AvenirNext-Regular", size:24.0)
        let myString1Color1 = UIColor(red: 0.292745, green: 0.461693, blue: 0.998524, alpha: 1.000000)
        let originalNSString = myString1.string as NSString
        let myString1Range1 = originalNSString.rangeOfString(titleData)
        var myString1ParaStyle1 = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        myString1ParaStyle1.baseWritingDirection = NSWritingDirection.Natural
        myString1ParaStyle1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        myString1.addAttribute(NSUnderlineColorAttributeName, value:myString1Color1, range:myString1Range1)
        myString1.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:myString1ParaStyle1, range:myString1Range1)
        myString1.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value:myString1Font1!, range:myString1Range1)

        if component == 0 {
            myString1ParaStyle1.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
        } else if component == 1 {
            myString1ParaStyle1.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
        }

        return myString1
    }

    func pickerView(spinFuelAmount: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView {

        var pickerLabel = view as! UILabel!
        if view == nil {
            pickerLabel = UILabel()
            let hue = CGFloat(row)/CGFloat(pickerData.count)
            pickerLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: 1.0, brightness:1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }
        let titleData = pickerData[row]
        var myString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string:titleData)
        let myString1Font1 = UIFont(name:"AvenirNext-Regular", size:24.0)
        let myString1Color1 = UIColor(red: 0.292745, green: 0.461693, blue: 0.998524, alpha: 1.000000)
        let originalNSString = myString1.string as NSString
        let myString1Range1 = originalNSString.rangeOfString(titleData)
        var myString1ParaStyle1 = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        myString1ParaStyle1.baseWritingDirection = NSWritingDirection.Natural
        myString1ParaStyle1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        myString1.addAttribute(NSUnderlineColorAttributeName, value:myString1Color1, range:myString1Range1)
        myString1.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:myString1ParaStyle1, range:myString1Range1)
        myString1.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value:myString1Font1!, range:myString1Range1)
        pickerLabel!.attributedText = myString1

        if component == 0 {
            myString1ParaStyle1.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
        } else if component == 1 {
            myString1ParaStyle1.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
        }


        return pickerLabel
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView {
        let pickerLabel = UILabel()
        let titleData = pickerData[row]
        let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 26.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor()])
        pickerLabel.attributedText = myTitle
       return pickerLabel
    }
```

and this:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let titleData = pickerData[row]
    var myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 15.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blueColor()])
    return myTitle
}
```

For the Attributed string, this is where you can modified the text attributes to fit what you want, you can set up something like this, you'll have to figure out how to place the Attributed string, but it's very simple using the second method above:

```
var myString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"$45.45")

let myString1Font1 = UIFont(name:"AvenirNext-Regular", size:24.0)

let myString1Color1 = UIColor(red: 0.292745, green: 0.461693, blue: 0.998524, alpha: 1.000000)

let originalNSString = myString1.string as NSString
let myString1Range1 = originalNSString.rangeOfString("$45.45")

var myString1ParaStyle1 = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
myString1ParaStyle1.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
myString1ParaStyle1.baseWritingDirection = NSWritingDirection.Natural
myString1ParaStyle1.defaultTabInterval = 0
myString1ParaStyle1.firstLineHeadIndent = 0
myString1ParaStyle1.headIndent = 0
myString1ParaStyle1.hyphenationFactor = 0
myString1ParaStyle1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
myString1ParaStyle1.lineHeightMultiple = 0
myString1ParaStyle1.lineSpacing = 0
myString1ParaStyle1.maximumLineHeight = 0
myString1ParaStyle1.minimumLineHeight = 0
myString1ParaStyle1.paragraphSpacing = 0
myString1ParaStyle1.paragraphSpacingBefore = 0
myString1ParaStyle1.tailIndent = 0

myString1.addAttribute(NSUnderlineColorAttributeName, value:myString1Color1, range:myString1Range1)
myString1.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:myString1ParaStyle1, range:myString1Range1)
myString1.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value:myString1Font1!, range:myString1Range1)
```

This seems to work:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let titleData = pickerData[row]

    var myString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string:titleData)
    let myString1Font1 = UIFont(name:"AvenirNext-Regular", size:24.0)
    let myString1Color1 = UIColor(red: 0.292745, green: 0.461693, blue: 0.998524, alpha: 1.000000)
    let originalNSString = myString1.string as NSString
    let myString1Range1 = originalNSString.rangeOfString(titleData)
    var myString1ParaStyle1 = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    myString1ParaStyle1.baseWritingDirection = NSWritingDirection.Natural
    myString1ParaStyle1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    myString1.addAttribute(NSUnderlineColorAttributeName, value:myString1Color1, range:myString1Range1)
    myString1.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:myString1ParaStyle1, range:myString1Range1)
    myString1.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value:myString1Font1!, range:myString1Range1)

    if pickerView == myPickerf {
        myString1ParaStyle1.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
    } else if pickerView == myPicker {
        myString1ParaStyle1.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
    }

    return myString1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView {
    var pickerLabel = view as! UILabel!
    if view == nil {
        pickerLabel = UILabel()
        let hue = CGFloat(row)/CGFloat(pickerData.count)
        pickerLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: 1.0, brightness:1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
    let titleData = pickerData[row]
    var myString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string:titleData)
    let myString1Font1 = UIFont(name:"AvenirNext-Regular", size:24.0)
    let myString1Color1 = UIColor(red: 0.292745, green: 0.461693, blue: 0.998524, alpha: 1.000000)
    let originalNSString = myString1.string as NSString
    let myString1Range1 = originalNSString.rangeOfString(titleData)
    var myString1ParaStyle1 = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    myString1ParaStyle1.baseWritingDirection = NSWritingDirection.Natural
    myString1ParaStyle1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    myString1.addAttribute(NSUnderlineColorAttributeName, value:myString1Color1, range:myString1Range1)
    myString1.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:myString1ParaStyle1, range:myString1Range1)
    myString1.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value:myString1Font1!, range:myString1Range1)
    pickerLabel!.attributedText = myString1

    if pickerView == myPickerf {
        myString1ParaStyle1.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
    } else if pickerView == myPicker {
        myString1ParaStyle1.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
    }


    return pickerLabel
}
```

Here's your code reformatted, this should work:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class LocationViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var DisplayStartMileage: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelFuelAmount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var spinFuelAmount: UIPickerView!

    var mileageToPass: String!

    var fuelAmount: Double = 0.00

    var pickerData = [[String]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var poundValues = [String]()
        var penceValues = [String]()
        for var indexP:Int = 0; indexP < 100; indexP += 1 {
            poundValues.append("£ \(indexP)")
            penceValues.append(NSString(format: ".%02d", indexP) as String)
        }

        self.pickerData = [poundValues, penceValues]

        spinFuelAmount.delegate = self
        spinFuelAmount.dataSource = self

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func FuelSegmentChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex
        {
        case 0:
            labelFuelAmount.hidden = false
            spinFuelAmount.hidden = false

        case 1:
            labelFuelAmount.hidden = true
            spinFuelAmount.hidden = true

        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(spinFuelAmount: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView(spinFuelAmount: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData[component].count
    }

    func pickerView(spinFuelAmount: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return pickerData[component][row]
    }

    func pickerView(spinFuelAmount: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        var firstComponent = pickerData[0][spinFuelAmount.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
        firstComponent = firstComponent.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( "£ ", withString: "" )

        var secondComponent = pickerData[1][spinFuelAmount.selectedRowInComponent(1)]
        secondComponent = secondComponent.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( ".", withString: "" )

        if let firstValue = firstComponent.toInt(), let secondValue = secondComponent.toInt() {
            let fuelAmount = firstValue + secondValue / 100
        }

    }

    func pickerView(spinFuelAmount: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {

        let titleData = pickerData[component][row] //this is bad, you'll have to compute what to do about this, but you get the point
        var myString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string:titleData)
        let myString1Font1 = UIFont(name:"AvenirNext-Regular", size:24.0)
        let myString1Color1 = UIColor(red: 0.292745, green: 0.461693, blue: 0.998524, alpha: 1.000000)
        let originalNSString = myString1.string as NSString
        let myString1Range1 = originalNSString.rangeOfString(titleData)
        var myString1ParaStyle1 = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        myString1ParaStyle1.baseWritingDirection = NSWritingDirection.Natural
        myString1ParaStyle1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        myString1.addAttribute(NSUnderlineColorAttributeName, value:myString1Color1, range:myString1Range1)
        myString1.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:myString1ParaStyle1, range:myString1Range1)
        myString1.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value:myString1Font1!, range:myString1Range1)

        if component == 0 {
            myString1ParaStyle1.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
        } else if component == 1 {
            myString1ParaStyle1.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
        }

        return myString1
    }

    func pickerView(spinFuelAmount: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView {

        var pickerLabel = view as! UILabel!
        if view == nil {
            pickerLabel = UILabel()
            let hue = CGFloat(row)/CGFloat(pickerData.count)
            pickerLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: 1.0, brightness:1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }
        let titleData = pickerData[component][row]
        var myString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string:titleData)
        let myString1Font1 = UIFont(name:"AvenirNext-Regular", size:24.0)
        let myString1Color1 = UIColor(red: 0.292745, green: 0.461693, blue: 0.998524, alpha: 1.000000)
        let originalNSString = myString1.string as NSString
        let myString1Range1 = originalNSString.rangeOfString(titleData)
        var myString1ParaStyle1 = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        myString1ParaStyle1.baseWritingDirection = NSWritingDirection.Natural
        myString1ParaStyle1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        myString1.addAttribute(NSUnderlineColorAttributeName, value:myString1Color1, range:myString1Range1)
        myString1.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:myString1ParaStyle1, range:myString1Range1)
        myString1.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value:myString1Font1!, range:myString1Range1)
        pickerLabel!.attributedText = myString1

        if component == 0 {
            myString1ParaStyle1.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
        } else if component == 1 {
            myString1ParaStyle1.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
        }


        return pickerLabel
    }
}
```

You will need to check my work and make sure that when THIS is called:

```
let titleData = pickerData[component][row]
```

that it's actually pointing to the correct dictionary item which is either Pounds or Pense. I actually looked at your code, more and I see that you had  pickerData[component][row] already, so I reformated and then used these for the mutableatributed string callers. see the revised code which is really your code but with the correction

Comment: Thanks.... this is similar to the code I found @ makeapple.com unfortunately when I use the top two bits of code... I get a Swift compiler error... Cannot find an initializer for type 'NSAttributedString' that accepts an argument list of type '(string: ([(String)]), attributes: [String : NSObject])' in both the let myTitle lines

Comment: Yep, same thing at MakeApple.com, let me check on the error portion for you, one sec

Comment: Thanks.... if it helps I am running Apple Swift version 1.2 (swiftlang-602.0.53.1 clang-602.0.53)

Comment: BTW... I may have introduced confusion in my question. My picker view has two spinners (columns) not as I put it rows. The user can spin the £ column (£0 - £99) independently to the pence column (.00 - .99) so that they can select any amount from £0.00 to (£99.99). It is the alignment of these columns that I need.

Comment: for sure, np, the solution I just posted will allow you to adjust the two pickers independently, you just have to tweak the NSTextAlignment of the POUNDS whole number to RIGHT and then tweak the PENCE to the LEFT and you should have it

Comment: look at the revised answer now, it does it with two  pickers, just use an If/then

Comment: Larcerax... thanks. The code makes sense in that I follow it (which is a good start :)) just getting one last error on each of the var myString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string:titleData) lines The error I get is Cannot find an initializer for type 'NSMutableAttributedString' that accepts an argument list of type '(string: ([(String)]))'

Comment: Still? that's terrible, I'm not getting that error at all, one sec, let me see what's going on

Comment: Perfect, let me compile it

Comment: okay, look at the bottom of my answer for more details, this may work

Comment: actually, now look at it, we are getting close

Comment: I see what you are doing, it's due to you using the two level deep array, let me work on this one, I get it

Comment: In fact, here's your solution, i think this sovles, it, I'm just going to repost your code in my answer, and rmeove the previous small answers, this is now in my answer, look at this line:   let titleData = pickerData[0][row]
 and this line    let titleData = pickerData[1][row]   the first one looks returns POUNDS and the second one returns the PENCE, this is becuase you declared pickerData as a "dictionary" of two strings side by side

Comment: and in fact, it's really suppose to be this: pickerData[row][row]

Comment: Thank-you so much... Swift is good but a steep learning curve from VB.net

Comment: Oh boy, Mych, coming from VB.net!! Yes sir, it's a huge change, but looks like you are doing pretty well

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps a better approach .... The following method could be of help:

```
// Swift
//   UIPickerView Delegate method

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(50.0)
}
```

Using this, the "bloat" of code could be removed and the following achieved with 2 components:

[image: centered and tight components]

By default the components will center align, and it appears the whole picker will also center align.

Answer (score 7):

I used this to right justify text in a pickerview:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
  var pickerLabel: UILabel? = (view as? UILabel)
  if pickerLabel == nil {
    pickerLabel = UILabel()
    pickerLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
    pickerLabel?.textAlignment = .right
  }

  pickerLabel?.text = data[row]
  pickerLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red

  return pickerLabel!
}
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer, way cleaner than the currently selected one. Should only be noted that data[row] should be changed to whatever your data variable is.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone trying to align multiple components like in UIDatePicker, i'm doing this for my Month & Year only picker view:

I have a String extension to calculate the width:

```
extension String {
func width(withConstraintedHeight height: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
    let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)

    return ceil(boundingBox.width)
}
}
```

Then i use it to calculate the width of the biggest value in each component and set its width in pickerview delegate

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    let componentValues = self.pickerViewDataSource[component]
    var maxWidth = CGFloat(0)

    for value in componentValues {
        let valueWidth = value.width(withConstraintedHeight: 20, font: self.pickerLabelFont)
        if valueWidth > maxWidth {
            maxWidth = valueWidth
        }
    }

    return maxWidth + 5
}
```

and now i create the label using the same font used to calculate the width

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView,
                viewForRow row: Int,
                forComponent component: Int,
                reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView
{

    var pickerLabel = view as? UILabel;

    if (pickerLabel == nil)
    {
        pickerLabel = UILabel()

        pickerLabel?.font = self.pickerLabelFont
        pickerLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    }

    if component < self.pickerViewDataSource.count && row < self.pickerViewDataSource[component].count {
        pickerLabel?.text = self.pickerViewDataSource[component][row]
    }

    pickerLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    return pickerLabel!;
}
```

This makes each component in the UIPickerView uses only the width it needs to display the biggest value. By default, UIPickerView will center align the components, so it will stay close each other, that why I've put the +5 for a margin. See below the example of how my picker is now:

[image: my picker view]

Answer (score -1):

You should achieve this by implementing the method:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView {

}
```